# flexbox form not filling up full width of available space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the situation below:

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: red;
}

.search-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="/">
    <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Test form</span>
      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="field" value="search" name="s" title="search input" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit button" value="search" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I need to have this flex form fill out full width, so that it covers the red but it won't for some reason...

[Flexbox: how to get divs to fill up 100% of the container width without wrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684759/flexbox-how-to-get-divs-to-fill-up-100-of-the-container-width-without-wrapping)

> to prevent the flex items from shrinking, set the flex shrink factor
> to 0:
>
> The flex shrink factor determines how much the flex item will shrink
> relative to the rest of the flex items in the flex container when
> negative free space is distributed. When omitted, it is set to 1.

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: red;
}

.search-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="/">
    <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Test form</span>
      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="field" value="search" name="s" title="search input" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit button" value="search" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Doesn't work..

I also attempted `width: 100%;`

Also from [Flexbox: how to get divs to fill up 100% of the container width without wrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684759/flexbox-how-to-get-divs-to-fill-up-100-of-the-container-width-without-wrapping)

> In my case, just using flex-shrink: 0 didn't work. But adding flex-grow: 1 to it worked.

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: red;
}

.search-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="/">
    <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Test form</span>
      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="field" value="search" name="s" title="search input" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit button" value="search" />
  </form>
</div>
```

[Flexbox not full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455838/flexbox-not-full-width/50455875)

I already tried flex-grow above and it didn't do anything.

How do you make a flex form fill full width of it;'s parent container?

Comment: it is filling the full width... but it doesn't have a background color so you see the red color from the parent. Are you wanting the children (the `label` and the `input`) to be full width of the form?

Comment: so I wanted it to completely cover the red, as in full width in context of the container, `label` needed a `flex-grow` prop on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out you do it on the child

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: red;
}

.search-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sesrch-form label {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="/">
    <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Test form</span>
      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="field" value="search" name="s" title="search input" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit button" value="search" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your `body` element likely has a margin and wasn't set to a width of 100%. You also don't define the width of the parent container so, it's defaulting to `auto`.

This can be remedied as follows:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.form-container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I got tripped up its `flex-grow` on a child in my case the label.